# _msearch api is not workinging properly

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an elasticsearch cluster with multiple indexes and index patterns. Most of them work fine.

But for just one kind of log indexes, when I am querying via `_msearch` api and use index pattern (say `a-index-*`), I get an empty response

```
{"responses":[{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":0,"successful":0,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":0,"hits":[]},"status":200}]}
```

If I run the same query against index itself (say `a-index-2019-10`), I get the expected response. Also, if I use `_search` api against index pattern, the response is correct.

I am testing this using `curl`, so the issue is clearly in elasticsearch but I am unable to find out why.

**This query(on index) returns results**

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_msearch' -H 'content-type: application/x-ndjson'  --data $'{"index":["a-index-2019-10"]}\n{"version":true,"size":0,"query":{"match_all":{}}}\n'
```

**This query (on index pattern) returns nothing results**

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_msearch' -H 'content-type: application/x-ndjson'  --data $'{"index":["a-index-2019-10*"]}\n{"version":true,"size":0,"query":{"match_all":{}}}\n'
```

Comment: Could you please share the query? I've tried something in my ES but its working fine. Perhaps with your `index-name` pattern along with query, I can at least hope to replicate the issue. Also could you share the exact version of ES, I know it is 5 but just to have no loose ends, want to know the exact version of ES. (I've tried in both ES 5.5.2 and 7.3 and it works fine)

Comment: Could you also see if you observe anything in your logs while doing pattern search with `_msearch`. Also could you also narrow down to try and see if the pattern `a-index-2019-11*` works. If so then go a level below and try with `a-index-2019-1*` to see if it works and so on just to catch hold of exact pattern from where it fails.

Comment: @Kamal I have updated the description, nothing with `*` works. ES version is 5.6.5

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the query/curl you've shared. It works well in my machine. I'm assuming you would have `10` indexes from `a-index-2019-01` to `a-index-2019-10` Could you verify one by one if any index, using the query 1(the one that returns the result), if any of it **does not** return any result.